Show Quantity on product page (configurable product)
I currently try setting up configurable product for our store, for example we sell a laptop with 3 grading A / A- / B and each grading has its own quantity and price.
When setting the correct price / quantity to its respective grading all looks good but it wont show the exact quantity for that product on the frontend and only shows "in stock" while on a simpel product page it shows in stock and the quantity thats remaining.
See picture for example of a laptop with multiple gradings, the goal is to have one product with the gradings instead of having a simple product for each grade.
hope someone can help me out or point me in the right direction
